# How can I add vertical space before all instances of a particular style in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

In my Word document I'm trying to find a way to prefix any instances of the "Heading 2" (no matter what the actual text of the heading is) with a paragraph mark and 2 carriage returns.

I'm using Visual Basic to try and automate things. Help?

Comment: Is this to add a certain amount of spacing, or to create a specific pattern of control characters? In Word, Shift+ENTER inserts a "carriage return" ENTER inserts a paragraph mark. They can be used in Word Find/Replace as ^p (paragraph) and ^l (lowercase L).

Answer (score 0):

### Modify your style to include sufficient space before in the paragraph formatting for the style.

This is easily done through the Modify Style dialog but you indicate you want vba.

```
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2").ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 36
```

*Direct formatting is the way to make documents more complex, more subject to corruption, and harder to edit. **Make use of styles instead.***